# Focus MKMapView on NSString Latitude and Longitude Coordinates with MKCoordinateRegion

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I have a latitude and longitude coordinate that I would like to focus my map on. They are stored as NSStrings and converted to locations below:

```
NSString *placeLatitude = [elementCoords objectForKey:@"placeLatitude"];
NSString *placeLongitude = [elementCoords objectForKey:@"placeLongitude"];

CLLocationCoordinate2D location;
location.latitude = [placeLatitude doubleValue];
location.longitude = [placeLongitude doubleValue];
```

How would I modify the below to not focus on the user's current location, but on the latitude and longitude specified above?

```
MKCoordinateRegion mapRegion;
mapRegion.center = mapView.userLocation.coordinate;
mapRegion.span.latitudeDelta = 0.05;
mapRegion.span.longitudeDelta = 0.05;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would use [`setCenterCoordinate:animated:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/MKMapView/setCenterCoordinate%3aanimated%3a) in order to move the map focus point. If you're loading the view and want to have it set to the correct location immediately, set `animated:NO`, otherwise, if you want to pan the map to smoothly center on `location` then set `animated:YES`

`[mapView setCenterCoordinate:location animated:YES];`

Of course, this won't change the zoom level of the map view. If you want to update the zoom level you should use [`setRegion:animated:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/MKMapView/setRegion%3aanimated%3a). For example, if you want to zoom in twice as close:

```
// Halve the width and height in the zoom level.
// If you want a constant zoom level, just set .longitude/latitudeDelta to the
// constant amount you would like.
// Note: a constant longitude/latitude != constant distance depending on distance
//       from poles or equator.
MKCoordinateSpan span =
    { .longitudeDelta = mapView.region.span.longitudeDelta / 2,
      .latitudeDelta  = mapView.region.span.latitudeDelta  / 2 };

// Create a new MKMapRegion with the new span, using the center we want.
MKCoordinateRegion region = { .center = location, .span = span };
[mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
```

Comment: Awesome - how do I set the zoom level?

Comment: Updated my answer, let me know if the C syntax for creating the struct has any issues and I can update with a less inline version of it. This code was written using a brain-induced compiler :)

Comment: Bah, tried to compile in Xcode and figured out my inline struct definition failed, updated my answer again :)

Comment: Getting the error "Member reference base type int is not a structure or union" - any ideas?

Comment: Yup, missing comma between the member definitions in the struct. Updated answer once more.

Comment: Nailed it!! Thank you very much!

Comment: ;) Enjoy the iOS development!

Answer (score 8):

```
    MKCoordinateRegion region;
   CLLocation *locObj = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([placeLatitude doubleValue], [placeLongitude doubleValue])
                                                   altitude:0
                                         horizontalAccuracy:0
                                           verticalAccuracy:0
                                                  timestamp:[NSDate date]];
    region.center = locObj.coordinate;  
    MKCoordinateSpan span; 
    span.latitudeDelta  = 1; // values for zoom
    span.longitudeDelta = 1; 
    region.span = span;
    [self.mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
```

Comment: Hi, getting a handful of errors: cannot be statically allocated, property latitude not found on object collocation... any ideas

Comment: Close - getting an expected identifier error at the timestamp:nil line

Comment: Hmmm, still getting an expected identifier error. Any ideas on why?

Comment: @BhushanUparkar What if I want to update the location of MKMapView from other class. Lets say in my case: When I select a value in tableview, I assign the latitude & longitude to mapview in other class. But it isn't getting changed. Any suggestions, please help me. Thanks :)

Comment: @BhushanUparkar Please help me, I tried protocol & accessing the map view through class instance object. Nothing is working. Thanks :)

Comment: @BhushanUparkar Yes, I am confident of that

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED TO SWIFT 3**

```
let span = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: mapView.region.span.latitudeDelta / 2, longitudeDelta: mapView.region.span.latitudeDelta  / 2)

        // Create a new MKMapRegion with the new span, using the center we want.
        let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: location, span: span)

        mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not set the user current location as mapRegion center. You have to set the your coordinate as map center location

Comment: Thanks, any recommendations on how to convert what I've got to a single coordinate that can be used for this?

Comment: Take CLLocation object and set its coordinate.latitude and coordinate.longitude.

Comment: Can you add an example to your answer :)

Comment: CLLocation locationObject;
locationObject.latitude= @"your latitude";
locationObject.longitude=@"your longitude";
mapRegion.center = locationObject.coordinate;

Answer (score 0):

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D location;
location.latitude =  [[[matchingItems objectAtIndex:j] valueForKey:@"latitude"] doubleValue];
location.longitude = [[[matchingItems objectAtIndex:j] valueForKey:@"longitude"] doubleValue];

MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance (location, 2000, 2000);
[mywebView setRegion:region animated:YES];
```